# React Native: API calls work locally but not from APK

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, api, server

I have deployed a botpress application to AWS (EC2) with Dokku, following the [docs](https://botpress.com/docs/deploy/hosting) of botpress. To communicate with the bot I'm doing API calls to the IP address (52.xx.xxx.xx:3000).

This works fine when I'm running my RN app locally or when I test the API with Postmen. As soon as I release an APK I can't communicate with the API anymore, and I don't have a way to see why network requests are failing.

Since I'm not very experienced with servers, I'm assuming the problem lies somewhere in the server settings, thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using HTTP? in that case use `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

In order to view remote documents from an HTTP URL, cleartext network traffic support is required. On Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher, cleartext support is disabled by default and apps targeting Android 9.0 or higher will need to add the **android:usesClearTextTraffic="true**" flag in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

> If you are only working with HTTPS files, this flag is not required.